# Accessing the deserialised object from a different class

Tags: apex, rest-api, apex-variable

I am using the following class to deserialise a JSON object:

```
 //Method to deserialize the response body
    public static responseResource deserialize(httpResponse res){
      return (responseResource)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),responseResource.class);
    }
```

I then want to access the returned deserialised object in a separate function and assign its elements to salesforce fields.

So, for example if one of the deserialised fields is 'Description', how do I access it in another class?

The question is about this part of the last class:

```
  string description = <the 'Description' field from the deserialise (res) object returned by 'responseResource Query' class I don't know how to describe in the script>
```

Let me use the following to explain further:

First, helper function:

```
public static responseResource APIQuery(string domain){
    httpResponse res = callout(domain);
    if ( res.getStatusCode() == 200 && string.isNotBlank(res.getBody())){
        return deserialize(res);
    }
    return null;
}
```

And the function to access the variable:

```
    @future (callout=true)
        public static void FutureCallBasicUpdater(string domain)
            {

string description = <the 'Description' field from the deserialise (res) object returned by 'responseResource APIQuery' class I don't know how to describe in the script>
            }
```

Comment: When you are calling deserialize method, just take the output of that method in an instance of **responeResouce** class, and you can pass it anywhere and use the variable **description**.

Comment: Thank you Nitish, could you please explain with an example? I am new to Salesforce and at the early stages of learning APEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access like any normal variable. "Utility" in this example is the name of the class that contains APIQuery.

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void FutureCallBasicUpdater(string domain) {
    Utility.responseResource res = Utility.APIQuery(domain);
    string description = res.Description;
}
```

Since you're trying to access the data across classes, the class and the Description value must be public:

```
public class resourceResponse {
    public String Description;
    // more attributes here, as needed
}
```